# Matrix of distances between data in 2d Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have four `1-by-n` matrices. The first two matrices represent the position of `n` points in the `2D` plane (x and y component of position). The second two matrices represent the position of another `n` points in the `2D` plane.

I want to create an `n-by-n` matrix (say `M`) for which `M(i,j)` is the distance between point `i` in the first matrix and point `j` in the second matrix.

Could anyone help? any answers are highly appreciated.

- n is a large number so I'm searching for an efficient way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `pdist2` (see [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)):

```
x1=[1,2,3,4,5];
y1=[6,7,8,9,10];
x2=[1,1,1,1,2];
y2=[8,3,1,2,3];
mat1=[x1',y1'];
mat2=[x2',y2'];
M = pdist2(mat1,mat2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to compute the distances manually using [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
M = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus, x1(:), x2(:).').^2 + bsxfun(@minus, y1(:), y2(:).').^2);
```