# How to compare any value in one matrix with any value in another matrix without using loops?

Tags: matlab

In the code below I have x any y coordinates of 4 nodes. First two nodes i.e. 1 and 2 fall in category c (matrix c) while the last two i.e 3 and 4 fall in category d (matrix d). "dist" represents distance between all the nodes. Is there any command in matlab using which i can tell if any of the nodes in c is at a distance less than R from any of the nodes in d e.g something like

```
if distance of any of the nodes in C from any of the nodes in D > R
%do this
end
```

I can do it using for loops but looking for a shorter way. Thanks

```
x=[1 2 4 4];
y=[3 5 6 1];
range=R
dist=[0.7 1.6 3.5 3.5; 2.9 0.7 1.6 4.7; 4.9 2.9 0.7 5.5; 3.8 4.3 4.5 0.7];
c=[1 2];
d=[3 4];
```

Comment: you want to look at [`pdist2`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html), possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407122/matrix-of-distances-between-data-in-2d-matlab

Comment: Do you already have `dist`? Or is computing it part of the question? Also, what would the output be in your example, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your question, but from what I get the functions you are looking for are:

- `A>B` - the binary operators in Matlab compares elements
- `any` - returns true if any of the elements are true
- `pdist2(a,b)` - compares distance from all observations in a vector `a` with all observations in another vector `b`.

I will gladly update with a more precise answer, but then please provide a complete example of what you want.